# notifyDataSetChanged vs notifyItemInserted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm confused if we use the two methods to tell the adapter that data you point were changed so what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 5):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` can be thought of as a "major" change. You're telling the adapter that *everything* in the data set has changed, and so it should re-bind every single child.

`notifyItemInserted()` (and the other methods like `notifyItemRemoved()` etc) can all be thought of as "minor" changes. You're telling the adapter exactly *how* the data set has changed, and so it can perform optimizations (like only re-binding the affected children).

Notably, using the "minor" change methods will also give you nice animations by default, which makes it a lot easier for the user to see *what* changed in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation

[notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)):

> This event does not specify what about the data set has changed, forcing any observers to assume that all existing items and structure may no longer be valid. **LayoutManagers will be forced to fully rebind and relayout all visible views**.

[notifyItemInserted()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int))

> Representations of other existing items in the data set **are still considered up to date and will not be rebound, though their positions may be altered.**

Main difference is that `notifyDataSetChanged()` will cause more overhead since it will force LayouManagers to full rebind the views where as `notifyItemInserted()` will not rebound all the views again but rather alter positions for them.

For better performance, rely on `notifyDataSetChanged()` as a last resort. Use the more specific change events (like `notifyItemInserted()`) wherever possible for better efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

[`notifyItemInserted(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)) takes the position of your inserted item as an argument, notifies about that item insert and thus also shifts positions after that item.

[`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) notifies that the data set connected to the adapter has changed.